# Can we question about Hindu traditions?

Tags: discussion, scope

Can we discuss about Hindu Traditions? I feel it should be considered on topic, for example,

- Reason behind wearing Mangalsutra
- Why girls have sindhur(kumkum) on their forehead
- Why Hindus don't wear foot wears in their temples
- Why punjabi girls wear huge number of bangles for few days after their marriage

Comment: Sure, IMO, they must be on-topic.

Comment: About punjabi girls, I think it comes under Sikhism.

Comment: @Mr_Green They are Hindus actually..

Comment: @Mr_Green Would like your inputs on adityas answer as you said you have points to add to his answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is absolutely no reason why these should be off-topic. This is they very core of this website. On-topic indeed!